# Почему функции активации в нейронных сетях принимают такие маленькие значения?

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Ведь даже если значения функции активации были бы в значениях от -10 до 10, это бы позволило сделать сеть более гибкой, как мне кажется. Ведь проблема не может заключаться только в отсутствии подходящей формулы. Объясните пожалуйста, что я упускаю.

Comment: Relu кстати выдает например число 1_127,если на элементе сигнал 1_127.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не большой эксперт в этом, но как по мне, так области значений могут быть разными. Вы можете определить свою, похожую на сигмоиду, но ***дифференцируемую***, функцию, которая будет возвращать значения -10 до 10.

Области определения некоторых функций

- `ReLU` `[0 ,∞ )`
- `Leaky ReLU` `(-∞ ,∞ )`
- `GELU` `(-0.17 ,∞ )` - внезапно

В абстракции биологических нейронных сетей функция активации представляет собой ***скорость возбуждения потенциала действия в клетке*** (это наши значения как раз). Т.е. обычно, одного сигнала не достаточно для активации. Если мы будем использовать в качестве такой функции любые функции с положительным угловым коэффициентом, то может оказаться так, что нам придется   "кормить" наш нейрон сигналами до бесконечности (говорят также, что функция не нормализуема, а такие сети имеют нестабильную сходимость).

Эти проблемы решаются любой похожей на сигмоиду функцией. Сигмоида - это гладкая монотонная возрастающая нелинейная функция. В физическом смысле это выглядит так:

1. Реалистичная модель в 0.
2. Пришел сигнал. Скорость возбуждения резко возрастает.
3. Если приходят еще подобные сигналы, то скорость возбуждения достигает асимптоты, но уже не с такой скоростью. Или наоборот скорость резко возрастает.

Это, вроде как, отражает реальность, т.к. в жизни для возбуждения нейронов нужно какое-то время или еще какие-то ресурсы, поскольку нейроны не могут физически возбуждаться быстрее некоторой определённой скорости.

Но тут важно не это, а то, что желательно, чтобы наша функция имела асимптоты, т.е. некоторые пределы схождения.

И так выходит, что нам, по большому счету, не важно, какие предельные значения у скорости, т.к. к некоторому моменту скорость и так будет запредельной [типа выше скорости света, но в мире нейронов (-; ]. А если так, то нас больше интересует дифференцируемость нашей функции на участке определения функции, или характеристики изменения скорости. Другими словами, нас интересует как изгибается наша функция, а не куда она идет в конце концов. Поэтому, очевидно, достаточно долей от 0 до 1, чтобы знать угол наклона касательной, и достаточно области определения от -1 до 1, чтобы принять решение о корректировке методом обратного распространения ошибки. Т.е. это все для красоты и простоты, а не для чего-то там.

Приношу извинения, если описал недостаточно ясно или, не дай бог, неправильно.

P.S. *Функция должна быть дифференцируема на области значений для того, чтобы мы могли как раз пользоваться методом обратного распространения ошибки*.